# Change size of generated plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is code I've amended from https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html to stack 3 instead of 2 categories :
for a stacked barchart:

```
labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
p1 = [20, 35, 30, 35, 7]
p2 = [25, 32, 34, 20, 55]
p3 = [21, 361, 341, 205,151]

width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


ax.bar(labels, p1, width, label='p1')
ax.bar(labels, p2, width, bottom=p1, label='p2')
ax.bar(labels, p3, width, bottom=p2, label='p3')

ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

This code renders:

[image]
How to amend the code so that the size of the generated plot can be set? For other plots I've used:

```
figure(num=None, figsize=(14, 7), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
```

But this does not change the size for the above plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the subplot you can pass the figsize as a parameter, like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7))
```

If you already created the subplots object, you can use the following:

```
fig.set_figwidth(14)
fig.set_figheight(7)
```